# Apple script: How to get the message id of the currently selected message in outlook app

Tags: macos, outlook, applescript

I want to get the message id of the message currently open in outlook app during read mode in inbox on my mac using osa script.

so far I have tried this:

```
tell application "Microsoft Outlook"
    set currentMessage to selection
    set header to headers of currentMessage
end tell
```

And I got a response but headers do not have the message id

Mac OS Bir Sur, Apple M1
Outlook 16.46 Microsoft 365 subscription.

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to:

```
 get id of currentMessage
```

Works on Mojave with Outlook 16.44. (Exchange acct)

Comment: I tried this but it doesn’t give the message id, it gives some other kind of id.

Answer (score 0):

-- This works here:

tell application "Microsoft Outlook"
set currentMessage to selection

```
set thisID to id of currentMessage

get subject of message id thisID --> "test 1"
```

end tell

Comment: This id is not the message id, this is some kind of internal outlook message id. An email message id looks like <AM0P189MBXXXXXXXXXXD0A0@AM0P18XXXX706.EURP189.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM>
Are you getting something like this for the id on your system?

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean now. I get the following line in the result of your original script: 

Message-ID: <F8EE4679-0E09-43CD-8826-5168C6EA9D49@domaincom>

...so it's definitely in the headers on my system.

Comment: ok thanks, I will also add my system config to the question .